# css have a background color, text and an image in the same div

Tags: html, css

So I have a box where I need to display some text, have a red background color and also have an image at the right of the box.

The idea is that the text should be given priority and background color should still be red.

Here is an example but it overrides the background color:

```css
.test {
  background-color: #e64e56;;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px darkGray;
  color: white;
  background: url(http://thumb10.shutterstock.com/thumb_small/536008/103572833/stock-photo-small-flower-isolated-on-white-background-103572833.jpg) no-repeat top right;

}
```

http://jsbin.com/axohoc/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```css
.test {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px darkGray;
  color: white;
  background: #e64e56 url(http://thumb10.shutterstock.com/thumb_small/536008/103572833/stock-photo-small-flower-isolated-on-white-background-103572833.jpg) no-repeat top right;
}
```

You can either define `background-color`, `background-image`, `background-repeat` and `background-position` separately, or use the shortcut `background`. When using the latter, it will overwrite the specific rules you have set, in this case `background-color`

Here is the example, edited http://jsbin.com/axohoc/7/edit

Here you can read up on the specifics of the shorthand property, as well as the different specific background properties: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: Great awnser, you give alot of details